# Trouble with CTypes - calling C dll function

Tags: c, python-3.x, ctypes

I have the following C function exported from a dll

```
typedef struct _TStubMethod
{
    TBoolean stubAtEnd;
    TBoolean longStub;
} TStubMethod;


int JpmcdsStringToStubMethod
(char        *name,     
 TStubMethod *stubMethod 
);
```

In Python, I have defined the type & function and called the function as follows:

```
class TStubMethod(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('stubAtEnd', c_int),
        ('longStub', c_int)
    ]

def JpmcdsStringToStubMethod(dll, name, stubmethod):
    func = dll.JpmcdsStringToStubMethod
    func.argtypes = [POINTER(c_char), POINTER(TStubMethod)]
    func.restype = c_int
    return func(name, stubmethod)

stubFS = TStubMethod(False, False)
ret = JpmcdsStringToStubMethod(dll, 'F/S', byref(stubFS))
```

I am getting an error as follows. What am I doing wrong?

```
ArgumentError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-ec7303283f89> in <module>
     25 
     26 stubFS = TStubMethod(False, False)
---> 27 ret = JpmcdsStringToStubMethod(dll, 'F/S', byref(stubFS))

<ipython-input-55-c8ab0da16b04> in JpmcdsStringToStubMethod(dll, name, stubmethod)
      9     func.argtypes = [POINTER(c_char), POINTER(TStubMethod)]
     10     func.restype = c_int
---> 11     return func(name, stubmethod)

ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When passing *zero-terminated strings*, use *c_char_p*. According to [[Python 3]: *class* ctypes.**c_char_p**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_char_p):

> Represents the C `char *` datatype when it points to a zero-terminated string.

Translated to your code:

1. Change the function *argtypes* (1<sup>st</sup> one):

   ```py
   func.argtypes = [c_char_p, POINTER(TStubMethod)]
   ```
2. Use *bytes* (which is *Python*'s equivalent for `char*`). You can **either** (**not** both):

   - Converting *string* to *bytes* (to keep changes in *JpmcdsStringToStubMethod*):

     ```py
     return func(name.encode(), stubmethod)
     ```
   - Pass a *bytes* instance to *JpmcdsStringToStubMethod*:

     ```py
     ret = JpmcdsStringToStubMethod(dll, b"F/S", byref(stubFS))
     ```

Comment: I'm reasonalbly sure the strings are `NUL`-terminated, not `NULL`-terminated.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I'm not sure I understand. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte.

Comment: @CristiFati NUL is the byte correspondance for 0 (Check the ASCII table), NULL, on the other hand, is the pointer that points to the memory address 0 (as defined in C) and it can have other names (None in Python, nil in Pascal ...)

Comment: @MeherKhiari: Yes, *NUL* is char 0, but that's also referred to as *null* (disregard the case). Also, `#define NULL    0`. So, even if NULL is used by convention for pointers, a bunch of official *URL*s use "*Null-terminated strings*", and I'm sticking with it.

Comment: @CristiFati 'bunch of official URLs use "Null-terminated strings"', that's the problem. They are confusing people. NUL is an ASCII nomination which is language independent and can be used as name in any programming language, NULL is a C specific notation that has been introduced for pointers. Please don't mix the two.

Comment: @MeherKhiari An implementation can define that null pointers point to address 0, and does on modern systems. But that's not part of the standard. Regarding `NULL` and `NUL`: The first is a pointer, the last a character, but they are both called *null* in prose, especially when the difference is immaterial or obvious from context. </pedantic>

Comment: @MeherKhiari: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm, http://www.asciitable.com, (actually https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=2106&bih=910&ei=RFGSXN2hBeibmwXUoKZY&q=null+terminated+string&oq=null+terminated+string) speak for themselves. Even if using *NUL* would be technically more correct, it would confuse people more (because most of the articles uses *null*). But enough time wasted on a technicality. I changed it so there's no room for discussions like this one.